# Strange behaviour with Computed Columns in SQL-Server

Tags: sql-server

Whilst reading through my 70-433 exam book, I thought of something that I can see not working, yet I believe it does. The passage read something like:

> The column must also be marked as *PERSISTED*, which means that SQL Server physically stores the result of the computed column's expression in the data row instead of calculating it each time it is referenced in a query.

From this I understand two things:

1. A **non-persisted** computed column is calculated every time that it is referenced in a query
2. Because nothing is stored for the computed column, I assume no index can be created for the column.

After reading it, I thought that this was a bit strange as I have managed to create an index on a non-persisted column in a previous project.

How can an index be created for something that is not persisted and is this detrimental in the long run?

---

To prove this I have run the following SQL statement:

```
CREATE TABLE testTable
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    telephone VARCHAR(14),
    c_areaCode AS (SUBSTRING(telephone,0,5)),
    cp_areaCode AS (SUBSTRING(telephone,0,5)) PERSISTED
)

INSERT INTO testTable VALUES('09823 000000');
INSERT INTO testTable VALUES('09824 000000');
INSERT INTO testTable VALUES('09825 000000');

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_NotPersisted ON testTable(c_areaCode);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Persisted ON testTable(cp_areaCode);
```

And then run the following queries:

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE('ALL');
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
GO
SELECT cp_areaCode FROM testTable;
GO
SELECT c_areaCode FROM testTable;
```

Having looked at the query plan for the above code, I can see that both select queries are using the non-persisted index. Again, how?

[image]

Comment: For those that have the 70-433 book, the quoted text is at the top of page 111.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 2.Because nothing is stored for the computed column, I assume no
>   index can be created for the column.

This assumption is not true - [either kind can be indexed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292.aspx). The computed column must be [deterministic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178091.aspx) in either case but when the computed column is persisted, the requirement that the computation is also [precise](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187440.aspx) is relaxed (ie it can involve floating point operations).

> How can an index be created for something that is not persisted and is
>   this detrimental in the long run?

The result of the function is 'persisted' *in the index* in either case - the only difference is whether it is persisted in the table.